# Making a a font awesome icon tab-able for Tooltip accessibility

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, accessibility

I am working in a 508 compliance website and accessibility for non-sighted users is a priority. These users use screen readers (jaws) to navigate through the site blindly. Logically, they can not use a mouse so the tooltip must be accessed by tabbing to it with the keyboard. This is fairly easy to do if the tooltip was applied to an input field, but our accessibility manager is heart-set on using a font awesome icon for the tooltip. The problem with that is, the icon is not an input field, therefore it does not respect tab order.

I know there has to be a workaround for this. I am attaching a FIDDLE for this [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9smy9zwm/)

Here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label> <i id="fieldwithtooltip" class="fa fa-question-circle" data-trigger="click" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right" aria-describedby="tip1"></i>
    <span id="tip1" class="tooltip hidden" role="tooltip">Also known as User ID</span>

    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display:none;}
span[aria-hidden="true"] {display:none;}
span[aria-hidden="false"] {display:block;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tip1").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
});
```

Any ideas to give the font awesome icon "?" a tab focus?

Comment: Your `.hidden` class will hide content from everybody: screen reader and non-screen-reader users. Did you mean [`.visually-hidden`](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/tenydnblog/clip-hidden-content-better-accessibility-53456.html) (or `.element-invisible` if you prefer)?

Comment: Very useful content related to your question: http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/

Comment: Interesting indeed. I'll be scrutinizing this link today. The hidden class keeps it from showing up either way until it gets focus or click. I actually managed to give a tab order by wrapping it in a <a> tag. but that is firing up other accessibility discrepancies such as recognizing it as an actual hyperlink. I'm guessing an ARIA and role will take care of this problem. I'll post an answer here for future readers if I figure it out or someone else beats me to it :)

Comment: You can make the icon itself focusable just by adding tabindex="0" to the <i> element, but unfortunately, an element receiving focus is generally not enough for browsers to display the title-based tooltip in most (all?) browsers - as a consequence, tooltips are generally considered inaccessible also to sighted keyboard users, not just screenreader users.

Comment: By the way, you do have a label here, but it's not associated with the input: either add an id to the input and then add for="id_of_edit" to the label, or wrap the label around the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqaxnv8a/)

I added `tabindex="0"` to `<i>` and created a couple event handlers to toggle the aria attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#tip1").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
     $("#fieldwithtooltip").on("focus", function(){
           var target = "#" + $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
           $(target).attr("aria-hidden", "false");
     });
     $("#fieldwithtooltip").on("blur", function(){
          var target = "#" + $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
          $(target).attr("aria-hidden", "true");
     });
});
```

While this visibly works, I'm not sure how a screen-reader will respond.  Please, let me know if you run some tests.

Comment: I managed to build it differently, but this is a great solution! Thank you. I'll be sure to use this if my fix doesn't pass accessibility. good job!

Answer (score 0):

wrap icon inside an anchor tag to allow to on it by tab.
Foe anchor tag (define empty href) and add onclick to perform desired action.

```html
<a href onclick="someFun()"><i class="fa fa-close" ></i></a>
```